# Php Hide content if it's empty (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't understand how do not display my content if it's value is empty.
I'll explain. I have the next loop:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'name', 'filter' => '1', 'orderby' => 'post_id', 'order' => 'ASC' ) ); ?>

<?php while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<div class="example"> abc </div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I want to display **abc** if the 'filter' value = '1' And I don't want to display the **`<div class="example"> abc </div>`** if the `'filter' value = '2'`

How can I solve my problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: your code is very strange... your `$loop` is an array of elements, you're not looping on it, and you have an `endwhile`, do you have the associated `while` ?

Comment: Yep, the code is edited atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 

$array = array( 'post_type' => 'name', 'filter' => '1', 'orderby' => 'post_id', 'order' => 'ASC' );

$loop = new WP_Query( $array ); ?>

<?php while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<?php if ($array['filter'] == 1): ?>
<div class="example"> abc </div>
<?php endif; ?> <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Try this. Edited. I forgot the endwhile **and** reset_query();

Comment: Unfortunately now I have the error Notice: Undefined variable: array in /var/www/.../abc.php on line 58

Comment: What's on line 58?

Comment: <?php if ($array['filter'] == 1): ?>

Comment: Have you added the first row I gave you - $array = array( 'post_type' => 'name', 'filter' => '1', 'orderby' => 'post_id', 'order' => 'ASC' );

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php if ($filter_value == 1): ?>
<div class="example"> abc </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In the above code `<div class="example"> abc </div>` is shown only if `filter_value==1` is true

Comment: Unfortunately after this code I have the error : Notice: Undefined variable:

Comment: Can you edit your code please? It's exactly what I;m looking for

Comment: You will need to replace `$filter_value` with the actual variable name. In your case, it should be the `filter` element in the array

Comment: Also check this documentation for what functions are available in The Loop: https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop